# "Incorrect syntax near 'WHERE'" in Delete queries

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014

For about the past year I having an issue with having my delete queries recognize a where clause. I am not talking about big major complex queries. Even little simple queries.

Usually I am in a hurry so rather than try to analyze the issue I simply utilize a join on a subquery to specify which rows to delete.  But now I want to know what's going on.  I've looked other places on stackoverflow but those errors were always due to something obvious like a extra comma, or trying to use the where clause with an Insert values statement.

The culprit today is the following:

```
DELETE FROM prc_ContractChanges chgs
WHERE chgs.ChangeTypeID = 1
```

Similar constructs have worked fine for the last 19 years. So why all of a sudden does this throw the obscene error

> Incorrect syntax near 'WHERE'.

I tried to add a comment in response to one below but each attempt end with "an error occurred when adding this comment"  so UI am editing the original question

That suggestion below worked. So it occurred to me how would you identify the multiple tables in a delete with a join. So I put the alias in the delete clause. That worked.  It occurred to me that putting the alias in the delete clause with a single table delete would work as well.  It did.

Comment: Remove the alias chgs  from before and after the WHERE   I'm also assuming prc_ContractChanges is a table and not a stored procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use one of the following syntaxes:

```
DELETE prc_ContractChanges 
FROM prc_ContractChanges chgs
WHERE chgs.ChangeTypeID = 1 

DELETE prc_ContractChanges 
WHERE ChangeTypeID = 1
```

Comment: Yeah that works too.  I seem to have a vague recollection from around 2001, of getting an error when I tried to show the table in the Delete clause.  I remember because I was just coming from Access SQL and the resultant query was different  than those I used in Access.  (In those days I would make the query in the access GUI and have Access convert it to SQL.  But this never worked for Delete queries.)